# Sequelize nested data structure

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make a query on our postgresQL database using sequelize & nodeJS.

It's all working fine apart from the structure of the deeply nested relationships for the model.

My example:

```
{
      model: this.Parent,
      as: 'Parent',
      include: [
        {
          model: this.Child,
          as: 'child',
          include: [
            {
              model: this.nestedChild,
              as: 'nestedChild',
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
```

The data for the child and nestedChild is returned in the 'included' object, the problem is that the nestedChild is no longer in 'relationships' object for the child, instead it's one of it's params.
Example:

```
data: [proper array of Parent elements with defined 'child' relationship in 'relationships' object],
included: [
    {
        attributes: {
            nested-child: {
            (here are properties for my nestedChild)
            }
        },
    relationships: <------ this is missing, and should include my nestedChild
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the nested relationship query is fine. It was the JSON serializer after that step that didn't have the proper structure defined therefore it was missing once the response was sent to front-end.